# call variable in method within the same class

Tags: python

In this example code:

```
class new:
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list = list
    def math(self):
        average = sum(self.list)/len(self.list)
        total = sum(self.list)
        return len(self.list)
    def values(self):
        return self.list

list = new([1,2,3,4])
```

is there a way to call the average and total variables in the math method without putting it in the  return function (I want the math function to only return the length of the list)? I tried this:

```
list.math().average
```

but this gives an error. I want to be able to call the variables in one line. Any suggestions?

Comment: `print(list.average)` should work.

Comment: also, change average to `self.average` in class definition. same for total

Comment: @FatemehKarimi thanks! is there a way to call it in one line? I tried list.math().average but it gives an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them in instance attributes.

```
class new:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.list = l
    def math(self):
        self.average = sum(self.list)/len(self.list)
        self.total = sum(self.list)
        return len(self.list)
    def values(self):
        return self.list

mylist = new([1,2,3,4])
mylist.math()
print(mylist.average, mylist.total)
```

BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name, it replaces the built-in function with that name.

Comment: thanks! is there a way to call it in one line? I tried mylist.math().average but it gives an error?

Comment: You would need `math()` to `return self` if you wanted to be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class new:
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list = list

    def average(self):
        return sum(self.list)/len(self.list)

    def total(self):
        return sum(self.list)

    def get_length(self):
        return len(self.list)

list = new([1,2,3,4])
list.average()
list.sum()
list.get_length()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the global keyword:

```
class new:
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list = list
    def math(self):
        global average
        global total
        average = sum(self.list)/len(self.list)
        total = sum(self.list)
        return len(self.list)
    def values(self):
        return self.list
```